# cocoa: confused by apple reference: cocoa view guide

Tags: cocoa

The cocoa view guide describe how to create a custom view. but I'm confused whether the cocoa will call the initWithFrame: method of a view.

[image]

How to create a custom view.
[image: how to create a custom view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-initWithFrame:` will be called for your custom view only if you use **Custom View** palette in IB. If you create, for example, textfield in IB and set it class to your custom textfield subclass `-initWithFrame:` will not be called but `-initWithCoder:` will.

Answer (score -2):

I think the article is clear. If you create things in Interface Builder, `initWithFrame` will NOT be called; else, it will be called.